# How to create a Javascript function where it'll insert appropriate icons in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, font-awesome

I want to create a JS function *(preferably vanilla JS)* where every time I create a new `div`, it'll append the corresponding icon to the `summary`.

For example:

- When creating a new NOTE `div`, it'll attach the note icon in `summary`
- when creating a new WARNING `div`, it'll attach the warning icon in `summary`

```css
.info{
 background: skyBlue;
 }
 
 .warning{
 color: red; 
  background: pink;
 }
 
 .note{
 background: gold;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<div class = " info"> 
<details>
  <summary>Info</summary>
  <p>Some info</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = " warning"> 
<details>
  <summary>Warning</summary>
  <p>Notification</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = " info"> 
<details>
  <summary>Info</summary>
  <p>Another info</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = " note"> 
<details>
  <summary>Note</summary>
  <p>Some note</p>
</details>
</div> 

<hr>
<p> How I want the end result to look </p>

<div class = " info"> 
<details>
  <summary>Info <i class="fas fa-info"></i></summary>
  <p>Some info</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = " warning"> 
<details>
  <summary>Warning <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></summary>
  <p>Notification</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = " info"> 
<details>
  <summary>Info <i class="fas fa-info"></i></summary>
  <p>Another info</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = " note"> 
<details>
  <summary>Note <i class="far fa-sticky-note"></i></summary>
  <p>Some note</p>
</details>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, below is my attempt but I was unsure and slightly embarrassed to show my progress: let note = document.querySelectorAll(".note");
let sideInfo = document.querySelectorAll(".side-info");
let div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
let summary = document.querySelectoAll("summary");
let noteIcon = '<i class="far fa-sticky-note"></i>';
let warning = '<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>'

function addIcons(){
  div.forEach(element){
  if (div.classList.contains('note')){
    summary.append()
  }
  if (div.classList.contains('warning'))
      summary.append(warning);
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include this code—don't post lengthy code in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a `cards-container` to which you can append the different cards, and make a `newCard` function to actually make the elements you'll be appending.

```js
const classes = {
  note: 'far fa-sticky-note',
  info: 'fas fa-info',
  warning: 'fas fa-exclamation-circle'
}

const container = document.querySelector('.cards-container')

function newCard(type, content) {
  const cardDiv = document.createElement('div')
  cardDiv.classList = `card ${type}`
  cardDiv.innerHTML = `
    <details>
      <summary>${type[0].toUpperCase()}${type.slice(1).substring(0)} <i class="${classes[type]}"></i></summary>
      <p>${content}</p>
    </details>`
  container.appendChild(cardDiv)
}

newCard('info', 'dis be a cool info')
newCard('warning', 'warning. danger! danger!')
```

```css
.info{
 background: skyBlue;
 }
 
 .warning{
 color: red; 
  background: pink;
 }
 
 .note{
 background: gold;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<div class="cards-container">
</div>
```

With the following code you can add icons to the already existing cards.

You can select all "cards" (each card is given the class name `card`) elements, and add the corresponding icon to their summary by modifying the summary's `innerHTML`.

```js
const classes = {
  note: 'far fa-sticky-note',
  info: 'fas fa-info',
  warning: 'fas fa-exclamation-circle'
}

const cards = [...document.querySelectorAll('.card')]

cards.map(el => el.querySelector('summary').innerHTML += " <i class=\"" + classes[el.classList[1]] + "\"></i>")
```

```css
.info{
 background: skyBlue;
 }
 
 .warning{
 color: red; 
  background: pink;
 }
 
 .note{
 background: gold;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous"> 

<div class = "card info"> 
<details>
  <summary>Info</summary>
  <p>Some info</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = "card warning"> 
<details>
  <summary>Warning</summary>
  <p>Notification</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = "card info"> 
<details>
  <summary>Info</summary>
  <p>Another info</p>
</details>
</div> 

<div class = "card note"> 
<details>
  <summary>Note</summary>
  <p>Some note</p>
</details>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Daisho, 
Thank you for your patience and answering my question! I actually liked the first function you created before the edit as it was short and comprehensible (not needing any if statements, append, etc). If I may ask, is there a reason why the edit was made? :0

Comment: @KO-d14 This is a more dynamic approach of appending whole card components from a function, instead of just adding to the already existing cards. But sure, I will add the previous answer to this one

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarification as well as the edit, I wanted to understand the logic of the functions you created. :) I really liked the two different approaches you created for varied situations!